# Continuity is not guaranteed even when the function is closed and convex. Why?

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Can you please give an example of a convex and closed function that is not continuous?

Comment: A proper convex function is closed if and only if it is lower semi-continuous. : in here you have example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity

Comment: An "easy" way to see this is closed unbounded operators exist.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ via
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x = 0, \\ \infty & \text{else}.\end{cases}$$
Clearly, this function is closed and convex (its epigraph is closed and convex), but not continuous.

Comment: Please draw a graph of function.